# Loop though body only of an email

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I want to run a macro only affecting the body of the email currently open (e.g., not the signature).

The code below works if the body is selected. How can we do it without need for selecting?

```
Sub FixParagraphSpacing()

    Dim objOL As Application
    Dim sel As Object

    Set objOL = Application
    Set sel = objOL.ActiveInspector().WordEditor.Application.Selection

    For Each para In sel.Paragraphs
        para.SpaceBefore = 0.3 * 11
        para.SpaceAfter = 0
    Next para

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
Sub FixParagraphSpacing()
     Dim objOL As Application
     Dim doc As Object
     Dim para As Object

     Set objOL = Application
     Set doc = objOL.ActiveInspector().WordEditor

     For Each para In doc.Paragraphs
         para.SpaceBefore = 0.3 * 11
         para.SpaceAfter = 0
     Next para
 End Sub
```