# Search for the absence of text in email body

Tags: vba, outlook

Everyday, I receives nearly 100+ emails which contain the following.

```
CRM Status: Open
CRM Interaction Number: XXXXX
```

On some emails Status and Number are missing.
Example:

```
CRM Status: 
CRM Interaction Number:
```

I need to look manually and categorize as "Not Ticketed".

Is there a way to find how many emails don't have the Ticket# and Status.

Comment: Yes you can loop through the Body of the Email and find the String using VBA. [Might Give you an Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31265985/loop-though-body-only-of-an-email)

Comment: Try to find what is between the : and vbNewLine.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717844/find-carriage-return-in-a-mail-body and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001670/vba-outlook-body-string-search

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that a VBA can use to find out how many emails doesn't have the Ticket# and Status.

The Outlook object model provides the `Find`/`FindNext` and `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class. You can read more about these methods in the following articles:

[How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)

[How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Also, you may find the [AdvancedSearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the `Application` class helpful.

The key benefits of using the `AdvancedSearch` method in Outlook are:

- The search is performed in another thread. You don’t need to run another thread manually since the `AdvancedSearch` method runs it automatically in the background.
- Possibility to search for any item types: mail, appointment, calendar, notes etc. in any location, i.e. beyond the scope of a certain folder. The `Restrict` and `Find`/`FindNext` methods can be applied to a particular `Items` collection (see the `Items` property of the `Folder` class in Outlook).
- Full support for DASL queries (custom properties can be used for searching too). You can read more about this in the [Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208216%28v=office.12%29) article in MSDN. To improve the search performance, Instant Search keywords can be used if Instant Search is enabled for the store (see the `IsInstantSearchEnabled` property of the `Store` class).
- You can stop the search process at any moment using the `Stop` method of the `Search` class.

Read more about this method in the [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) article.